# mysql to php email setup

Tags: php, mysql, email

I am trying to send an email to an email address in my mysql table with the information on that row. My code is stopping at the date, time and sent check. I am unsure about this line. Please see my code below. It is a PHP only file as this will become a cron job.

My date and time are entered by the person entering the data.
Date Format: 2015-05-07
Time Format: 14:32

I am getting this error
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':06 || sent = NULL' at line 1

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />


<?php

require ('class.phpmailer.php');
require ('login.php');

$link = mysql_connect($REMINDER_DB_HOST, $REMINDER_DB_USER, $REMINDER_DB_PASSWORD);

if (!link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($REMINDER_DB_NAME, $link);

if (!db_selected) {
die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ' : ' . msql_error());
}
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$now = date("H:i");

echo $today;
echo $now;

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM alert WHERE date < $today || time < $now || sent = NULL") or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {


$name = $row['name'];
$to = $row['email'];
$date = $row['date'];
$time = $row['time'];
$eslticket = $row['eslticket'];
$notes = $row['notes'];

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$g_smtp_connection_mode   = 'ssl';
$g_phpMailer_method        = 2;
$g_smtp_host              = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$g_smtp_port              = 465;
$g_smtp_username          = $mailuser;
$g_smtp_password          = $mailpassword;



$subject = 'ESL Ticket Reminder: ' .$eslticket;
$msg = 'Good Day, '.$name.'\n'.'You have requested an alert email to be sent to you about '.$eslticket.' on '.$date.' at '.$time.'. Please see below to review your notes on this ticket.'.'\n'.'\n'.$notes;

if(mail($to, $subject, $msg)) {
$sql = "INSERT INTO alert (sent) VALUES ('1')";
} else {

}

}
?>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: duplicate - why post again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM alert WHERE date < '$today' OR time < '$now' OR sent = NULL") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forgot to click on the thick on the left of the answer to set it as resolved.

Comment: zeflex 2 questions why is it not looping and why is it not entering 1 in the sent column?

Comment: `while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))`  >> do a var_dump to check the output of $row. 2) You are calling PhpMailer but you use `if(mail($to, $subject, $msg))` >> not using phpmailer. 3) `$sql = "INSERT INTO alert (sent) VALUES ('1')";` that's cool but where is the `mysql_query` instruction ? Also, I guess you want more to update a row than inserting new ones. 4) Take your time and debug your code step by step

Comment: 1) my var_dump only gives me one line, 2) I updated my mail to $mail->addAddress($to);
$mail->Subject = 'ESL Ticket Reminder: ' .$eslticket;
$mail->Body    = 'Good Day, '.$name.'<br/>'.'You have requested an alert email to be sent to you about '.$eslticket.' on '.$date.' at '.$time.'. Please see below to review your notes on this ticket.'.'<br/><br/>'.$notes;

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
 $sql = "INSERT INTO alert (sent) VALUES ('1')";
}

Comment: 1) should it returns one line ?
2) About the phpmailer code I cannot read here in comments, too hard. But why are you using INSERT instead of UPDATE ... WHERE ... syntax ? You will simply add an entry with INSERT not related to the SELECT query you did before. Also after the `$sql = 'INSERT ... (better to use UPDATE)';` , run the `mysql_query($sql);` ... !

Comment: It should loop until the date and time are no longer in the past. I have three rows and two are past and one is future in this case it should send two separate emails. I have change it to update. Here is my var_dump array(8) { ["idalert"]=> string(2) "10" ["name"]=> string(14) "John Stilwell " ["email"]=> string(23) "stilwellj1983@gmail.com" ["date"]=> string(10) "2015-05-07" ["time"]=> string(5) "10:59" ["eslticket"]=> string(11) "ESL01856595" ["notes"]=> string(6) "Test 1" ["sent"]=> string(1) "1" }

Comment: Open a new question for this